# "Element resources must be declared" after adding values for dark mode

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I was trying to add another values directory for the night mode of the app. I created the values directory and copied the colors.xml file in it. But I am facing this resource type must be declared issue. Please help me in solving this issue.[image: Error in copied colors.xml file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your directory is `values - dark` - you need to remove the spaces and change it to `values-night` (there is no `dark` qualifier and spaces are not valid).